# Moq.proxy.castleproxyfactory TypeInitialization error

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, castle

I get the following error when setting up a mock using Moq using Moq 4.7.145 and Castle.Core 4.2.1

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc"}

   at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.get_Instance()
   at Moq.Mock.ThrowIfSetupMethodNotVisibleToProxyFactory(MethodInfo method) in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 823
   at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass67_0`2.<Setup>b__0() in C:\projects\moq4\Source\Mock.cs:line 481
```

Comment: Remove then re-add the Moq package there may be a conflict. Also check config file for any binding redirects

Comment: What is the question exactly?